# Specific g++ version using chef-solo

Tags: c++, g++, chef-infra, chef-solo

I wanted to install specific version of g++ using chef solo, but weren't able to find any references to do that. How can i do that?

my sample metadata.rb:

```
name             'default_server'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures default_server'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'

depends 'rvm',             '~> 0.9'
depends 'git',             '~> 4.0'
depends 'mongodb',         '~> 0.16'
depends 'redisio',         '~> 3.0'
```

My sample Berksfile

```
source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"

cookbook 'sudo'

cookbook 'rvm',             '~> 0.9'
cookbook 'git',             '~> 4.0'
cookbook 'mongodb',         '~> 0.16'
cookbook 'redisio',         '~> 3.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this question is hugely broad, if you are installing from packages you can control the version of a package like this:

```
package 'g++-package-name' do
  version 'version-you-want'
end
```

Comment: I was so much into configuring vagrant with berkshelf, that forgot about chef basic abilities. Thanks for reminding.